# Change an input controls value using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using a input control with a type of file to allow users to upload images.  When I handle the upload I'm using the WebImage.GetImageFromRequest() to get the submitted image.  This works great, unless the user's image file name has an extension that isn't in lowercase.  So, myimage.jpg works, but myimage.JPG will not.  This is a [documented](http://forums.asp.net/t/1682158.aspx/1) problem, with no know solution.

I'm trying to get around this issue by renaming the value entered in jQuery, but I can't get it to work.  I have a function that checks for valid extensions, and I thought I could add code here that would convert the value to all lowercase, but the val() method doesn't seem to be setting the value as expected.

```
       $("#uploadimagebutton").click(function (e) {
           var fileName = $('input[name="fileUpload"]').val();

           var validFileTypes = ['gif', 'jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'bmp'];
           if (!fileName) {
               e.preventDefault();
               return;
           }
           fileName = fileName.toLowerCase();


           alert(fileName); //This displays my file name and path in all lowercase

           $('input[name="fileUpload"]').val(fileName); //This is FAILING


           alert($('input[name="fileUpload"]').val()); //Shows path unchanged (not lower)

           var dots = fileName.split(".")
           //get the part AFTER the LAST period.
           fileType = "." + dots[dots.length - 1];

           if (("." + validFileTypes.join(".")).indexOf(fileType) == -1) {
               e.preventDefault();
               alert("File Type: " + fileType + " is not allowed. \n Please only upload files that end in types: \n\n." + (validFileTypes.join(" .")) + "\n\nPlease select a new file and try again.");
           }
           return;
       });
```

You can see the two alerts I have with comments above.  So, my path could be something like,

```
 C:\Users\jreddy\Pictures\myimage.JPG
```

My first alert should show the lowered version of the above string and it does.

```
     c:\users\jreddy\pictures\myimage.jpg
```

I then set this value, using the val method, but when I do, my next statement shows my original string.

I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my jQuery, or it the input control just doesn't like being changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the file control is read-only.  So you can blank it, or read the value, but not change it (even though it seems like you can).

I see specific reference to IE not allowing this when I search google.

Comment: Yeah, I found this is the case. This is a security feature.  I've modified my code to get my image from Request.Files if the WebImage.GetImageFromRequest() is null. Thanks @Ryley